# Flatten types after composing two defs

Tags: scala, scalaz

following is a toy example to demonstrate real life legacy methods' shape weirdness and point of the question.

As you can see `anotherFunc`, after mapping over `personList` expands type to `\/[Throwable,List[\/[Throwable,String]]]` which isn't intended return type but effect of `map`ing `personList`. again what's illustrated below inside `anotherFunc` is for demo purpose(in reality there is more meaningful things happening instead of `Option("fakeString")` or any of that.

Requirement is to `map` `personList` and if it's `right` then do something with each element of the `List[Person]` returned from `right` (side that was returned from the disjunction).

how to simplify/flatten return type of `anotherFunc` (to return `\/[Throwable,List[String]]`). May be using other combinators?

```
case class Person(name :String)

def personList : \/[Throwable,List[Person]] ={
  \/.fromTryCatch{
    List(Person("John"))
  }
} 

def anotherFunc  : \/[Throwable,List[\/[Throwable,String]]]= {
  personList.map{ pl =>
    pl.map{p =>
      for{
        s <- Option("fakeString").\/>(new Throwable("not found"))
      } yield s

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Noah's answer is basically right, but you should always use `traverse` instead of a `map` followed by a `sequence`—the two are equivalent but the former is clearer and a little more efficient:

```
def anotherFunc: Throwable \/ List[String] = personList.flatMap { pl =>
  pl.traverseU { p =>
    for {
      // I assume you're doing something more interesting here...
      s <- Option("fakeString").\/>(new Throwable("not found"))
    } yield s
  }
}
```

I'm making this an answer instead of a comment, though, because there's another way to solve this kind of problem that can be more elegant in some situations. If you're doing a lot of work with lists of disjunctions, you can use the `ListT` monad transformer to make it look like you're dealing with a single level:

```
type OrThrowable[A] = Throwable \/ A    

def personList = ListT[OrThrowable, Person](
  \/.fromTryCatch { List(Person("John")) }
)

def anotherFunc: ListT[OrThrowable, String] = personList.flatMap { p =>
  Option("fakeString").\/>(new Throwable("not found")).liftM[ListT]
}
```

Now just use `anotherFunc.run` at the end to get a `Throwable \/ List[Person]` and this is exactly equivalent to your current code (but a lot more concise).

Comment: Thanks, @Noah, and sorry about the scoop—if `traverse` was all I was adding I would have made it a comment.

Answer (score 5):

If you `flatMap` the `personList` and then `sequenceU` the inner list you can basically `flatten` your return type:

```
  def anotherFunc: \/[Throwable, List[String]] = {
    personList.flatMap(
      pl =>
        pl.map(
          p =>
            for {
              s <- Option("fakeString").\/>(new Throwable("not found"))
            } yield s
        ).sequenceU
    )
  }
```

Intellij complains about this with some red lines but it compiles and prints out correctly for me `\/-(List(fakeString))`.

This version looks a little prettier in my opinion:

```
  def anotherFunc2: \/[Throwable, List[String]] = {
    for {
      pl <- personList
      res <- pl.map(p => Option("fakeString").\/>(new Throwable("not found"))).sequenceU
    } yield res
  }
```