# Is monad Transformation required here?

Tags: scala, scalaz

Older version of the API was looked something like this (credit to @travisbrown for suggesting `traverseU` solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340931/flatten-types-after-composing-two-defs)). Note that these two APIs are created as a toy example to illustrate the point on this SO question. Real code is doing more interesting things.

```
def anotherFunc: Throwable \/ List[String] = personList.flatMap { pl =>
  pl.traverseU { p =>
  for {
    s <- Option("fakeString").\/>(new Throwable("not found"))
  } yield s
 }
}
```

where

```
case class Person(name: String)

 private def personList: \/[Throwable, List[Person]] = {
   \/.fromTryCatch {
      List(Person("John"))
  }
}
```

Now converting this `def` to `Future` based will look like as follow

```
def anotherFunc: Future[Throwable \/ List[String]] = Future {
personList.flatMap { pl =>
  pl.traverseU { p =>
    for {
      s <- Option("fakeString").\/>(new Throwable("not found"))


    } yield s
  }
 }
}
```

Now as mentioned before this is a toy example but I have a one or more generators in that `for` comprehension which return disjunction wrapped in `Future` e.g. `Future[\/[Throwable,String]]`

you can imagine something like `s1` below

```
   for {
       s <- Option("fakeString").\/>(new Throwable("not found"))
       //s1 <- Future{"returning Future[\/[Throwable,String]" }
   } yield //value out of s1 future must be yielded
```

Is monad transformation needed here?

e.g. To get value of out `Future` monad (`s1` in this case) and transform to
appropriately to match with the return of `anotherFunc` ?  not sure if `EitherT` can help here?

**Update**

Simplifying the example. This is what `anotherFunc` looks like with one of the generators returning `Future[\/[Throwable,String]]`. Basically want to avoid using `Await`

```
def anotherFunc: Future[Throwable \/ List[String]] = Future {
personList.flatMap { pl =>
  pl.traverseU { p =>
    for {
      s <- Option("fakeString").\/>(new Throwable("not found"))
      f <- Await.result(futureResult, 1.seconds)
    } yield f
  }
}
}

def futureResult = Future{Option("""another Disjunction is called here - which returns a    Future[\/[Throwable,T]""").\/>(new Throwable("not found"))}
```

Comment: Monad transformers are never _necessary_, really, but they can make this kind of operation much more convenient—see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21993273/334519) for a very similar example.

Comment: @TravisBrown : Thanks. I did see that post but if the `func` is already wrapped in a `Future`,as shown in the post above,where `anotherFunc` is wrapped in `Future{}` and all other generators in there return disjunctions except this one which returns `Future[\/[Throwable,String]]` how to still align types in `for` comprehension and still satisfy `anotherFunc` return type which is `Future[Throwable \/ List[String]]`

Comment: @TravisBrown : Added an example in `Update` section to illustrate the problem. Thanks.